# Digital Certificate: How to import .cer file in to .truststore file using?

Tags: digital-certificate, truststore

Has anyone came across where they have to deal with .truststore file? and knowing how to import .cer into .truststore file?

I am not sure if I have to use Java Keytool or Linux command (such as openssl command).

Thanks

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
# Copy the certificate into the directory Java_home\Jre\Lib\Security
# Change your directory to Java_home\Jre\Lib\Security>
# Import the certificate to a trust store.

keytool -import -alias ca -file somecert.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit [Return]

Trust this certificate: [Yes]
```

changeit is the default truststore password

Comment: any one know how to do in openssl

Comment: This command let you download the certificate to a file namend certfile.txt: openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:PORTNUM 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > certfile.txt --- Then use keytool to import it in your trust store

Comment: You can download the certificate of any SSL secured website in your browser. In FireFox just doublclick the lock symbol in the URL address field.

Comment: if you have "jssecacerts" file , use "-keystore jssecacerts" instead.  "cacerts" is ignored

Answer (score 29):

Instead of using `sed` to filter out the certificate, you can also pipe the `openssl s_client` output through `openssl x509 -out certfile.txt`, for example:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect my.server.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -out certfile.txt
```

Comment: This answer was intended as an improvement to Christian's comment on the accepted answer about downloading the certificate. Probably should have been a comment.

Answer (score 11):

The way you import a .cer file into the trust store is the same way you'd import a .crt file from say an export from Firefox.

You do not have to put an alias and the password of the keystore, you can just type:

```
keytool -v -import -file somefile.crt  -alias somecrt -keystore my-cacerts
```

Preferably use the cacerts file that is already in your Java installation (jre\lib\security\cacerts) as it contains secure "popular" certificates.

*Update regarding the differences of cer and crt (just to clarify)*
According to [Apache with SSL - How to convert CER to CRT certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642284/apache-with-ssl-how-to-convert-cer-to-crt-certificates) and user @Spawnrider

> CER is a X.509 certificate in binary form, DER encoded. 
>   CRT is a binary X.509 certificate, encapsulated in text (base-64) encoding. 
>   It is not the same encoding.

Comment: All this means is that you exported the file  with a slightly different name. It doesn't change the file, the question, or the answer. It is wise to specify an alias: otherwise you risk overwriting a prior import.

Comment: Do .crt and .cer have the some format? Does the extension play no role in the certificates? Good point about the alias.

Comment: I answer my question: Yes, crt and cer have the same format. Same thing. You can import both in trust store.