# Do I need to convert .CER to .CRT for Apache SSL certificates? If so, how?

Tags: apache, ssl

I need to setup an Apache 2 server with SSL.

I have my *.key file, but all the documentation I've found online, *.crt files are specified, and my CA only provided me with a *.cer file.

Are *.cer files the same as *.crt? If not, how can I convert CER to CRT format?

Comment: `CER` and `CRT` extensions mean nothing. Different PKI vendors use different extensions for the same thing. If the file is binary, then its probably ASN.1/DER encoded. If the file is human readable with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, then its PEM encoded. What do you have (DER or PEM), and what do you need (DER or PEM)?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

File extensions for cryptographic certificates aren't really as standardized as you'd expect. Windows by default treats double-clicking a `.crt` file as a request to import the certificate into the Windows Root Certificate store, but treats a `.cer` file as a request just to view the certificate. So, they're different in the sense that Windows has some inherent different meaning for what happens when you double click each type of file.

But the way that Windows handles them when you double-click them is about the only difference between the two. Both extensions just represent that it contains a public certificate. You can rename a certificate file to use one extension in place of the other in any system or configuration file that I've seen. And on non-Windows platforms (and even on Windows), people aren't particularly careful about which extension they use, and treat them both interchangeably, as there's no difference between them as long as the contents of the file are correct.

Making things more confusing is that there are two standard ways of storing certificate data in a file: One is a "binary" X.509 encoding, and the other is a "text" base64 encoding that usually starts with "`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`". These encode the same data but in different ways. Most systems accept both formats, but, if you need to, you can convert one to the other via openssl or other tools. The encoding within a certificate file is really independent of which extension somebody gave the file.

Comment: My understanding is that they are _both_ X.509 encodings. You don't say otherwise, but the asymmetric use of x.509 above might suggest otherwise to a reader. To the reader, it's worth noting that the certificates can be converted back and forth between these 2 encodings, because as this answer mentions, they hold the same information. See the other answer with the openssl x509 -inform commands.

Answer (score 119):

Basically there are two CER certificate encoding types, DER and Base64. When type DER returns an error loading certificate (asn1 encoding routines), try the PEM and it shall work.

`openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

Comment: The DER format worked for me when my cer file looked like binary when I tried to edit it... thanks!

Comment: To the reader, I found the openssl man page useful. It was ambiguous to me which of the commands did what (i.e. which way was the conversion). The -inform parameter specifies the format of the input -in file, which is intuitive, but if you're already a little confused, it's nice to know explicitly. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html

Answer (score 56):

According to documentation [mod_ssl](http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_reference.html):

```
SSLCertificateFile: 
   Name: SSLCertificateFile
   Description: Server PEM-encoded X.509 certificate file
```

Certificate file should be PEM-encoded X.509 Certificate file:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Comment: Will this solve ssl cert errors, when behind `zscaler`, running `vagrant` on `win` (`vbox` `homestead`), by installing our trusted root certs into the vagrant box?  I `scp`'d them, then used your conversion and symlinked them into `/etc/ssl/certs` and also copied the contents into the `ca-certificates.crt` file before reprovisioning, and still im getting a `google-recaptcha` `tls` `ssl` error on `file_get_contents` on the dev box.

Answer (score 39):

**CER** is an X.509 certificate in binary form, **DER** encoded.
**CRT** is a binary X.509 certificate, encapsulated in text (**base-64**) encoding.

It is not the same encoding.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. Both .CER and .CRT can be using either DER or PEM (text) encoding. Extensions .pem and .der reflect the encoding, .cer and .crt do not. [More details](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them).

Comment: Actually, it *should* be the opposite. But all those extensions have been confused for a long time, so you should not rely on them.

Comment: can confirm. i have a .cer and it's binary

Comment: [RFC 2585](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2585) registers `.cer` for DER encoding and [RFC 7468](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-5.3) recommends `.crt` for the textual (Base64) form, but in practice the extensions are often mixed up.

Answer (score 37):

I use command:

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

But CER is an X.509 certificate in binary form, DER encoded.
CRT is a binary X.509 certificate, encapsulated in text (base-64) encoding.

Because of that, you maybe should use:

`openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

And then to import your certificate:

Copy your CA to dir:

`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`

Use command:

`sudo cp foo.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt`

Update the CA store:

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

Answer (score 32):

I assume that you have a .cer file containing PKCS#7-encoded certificate data and you want to convert it to PEM-encoded certificate data (typically a .crt or .pem file).  For instance, a .cer file containing PKCS#7-encoded data looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIW4gYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIW0zCCFs8CAQExADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggha1MIIH
...
POI9n9cd2cNgQ4xYDiKWL2KjLB+6rQXvqzJ4h6BUcxm1XAX5Uj5tLUUL9wqT6u0G
+bKhADEA
-----END PKCS7-----
```

PEM certificate data looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHNjCCBh6gAwIBAgIQAlBxtqKazsxUSR9QdWWxaDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBm
...
nv72c/OV4nlyrvBLPoaS5JFUJvFUG8RfAEY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

There is an OpenSSL command that will convert .cer files (with PKCS#7 data) to the PEM data you may be expecting to encounter (the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` block in the example above).  You can coerce PKCS#7 data into PEM format by this command on a file we'll call certfile.cer:

`openssl pkcs7 -text -in certfile.cer -print_certs -outform PEM -out certfile.pem`

Note that a .cer or .pem file might contain one or more certificates (possibly the entire certificate chain).

Comment: Would be handy if you had a source of this assumption. I think people use (possibly incorrectly) .cer, .crt, .pem interchangeably) so having a source of truth would correct the misconceptions.

Answer (score 17):

The answer to the question how to convert a .cer file into a .crt file (they are encoded differently!) is:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt
```

Comment: This not worked for me!
I used: `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem`

Comment: I'm getting this error message: `unable to load PKCS7 object`

Comment: @friederbluemle did you check out this answer? http://serverfault.com/questions/417140/convert-from-p7b-to-pem-via-openssl

Comment: This is what I had to do to get my positiveSSL cert ready to be converted into PKCS12 for use in Azure.

Comment: print_certs in windows command window was not valid options, this did not work

Answer (score 7):

If your cer file has binary format you must convert it by

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in YOUR_CERTIFICATE.cer -out YOUR_CERTIFICATE.crt
```

Answer (score 4):

The .cer and .crt file should be interchangable as far as importing them into a keystore.

Take a look at the contents of the .cer file. Erase anything before the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line and after the `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` line. You'll be left with the BEGIN/END lines with a bunch of Base64-encoded stuff between them.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDQTCCAqqgAwIBAgIJALQea21f1bVjMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIG1MQswCQYD
...
pfDACIDHTrwCk5OefMwArfEkSBo/
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then just import it into your keyfile using keytool.

```
keytool -import -alias myalias -keystore my.keystore -trustcacerts -file mycert.cer
```

Comment: The thing that helped me was your comment of BASE-64 ENCODING.  A normal cert apparently is special encoding and not plain text readable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one case that worked for me if we need to convert .cer to .crt, though both of them are contextually same

Generate crt file:
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -nokeys -out mycertificate.crt

Generate key file:
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -out mycertificate.key -nodes -nocerts

where we should have a valid private key (identity.p12) PKCS 12 format, this one i generated from keystore (.jks file) provided by CA (Certification Authority) who created my certificate.

Answer (score -2):

Just do

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.cer -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what this line does exactly and why exactly you use those parameters? This answer is quite short and may be hard to understand for people with less experience.