# Install .cer certificates debian

Tags: ssl, certificate, crt, cer

I have to install a certificates on my server, but they only gave me a .cer file. I search on some forums, but I don't find anything to install it, just for .crt files...

How could I install it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you found the solution for it? I also have the .crt file but key file is missing and have to enable SSL on AWS server.

Answer (score 2):

You must first convert the cer file into a crt file.

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in <fullfilepath>/certificate.cer -out certificate.crt
```

Then to install do the following:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-custom-ca
sudo cp certificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-custom-ca
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

You can find the full installation procedure [here](https://grumpytechie.net/2020/02/25/adding-custom-root-ca-certificates-to-debian/).

Answer (score 0):

`.cer` certificate is a Microsoft specific format. You can try to convert from `.cer` into `.crt` before installation following such a guide in the answer provided here: [convert_cer_to_crt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642284/do-i-need-to-convert-cer-to-crt-for-apache-ssl-certificates-if-so-how#642346)