# Update VS Code and Kaspersky certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kaspersky

I just wanted to start VS Code on Windows Subsystem Linux but VS Code updates automatically. The issue is a certificate which VS Code wants to access but it is blocked by kaspersky. Kaspersky is installed on Windows 10. I have the Total Securiy Version. Does somebody have a hint? What should I change?

> micha@LAPTOP-TD50FJUH:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32$ code .
> Updating VS Code Server to version 8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496
> Removing previous installation... Installing VS Code Server for x64
> (8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496) Downloading: 100% Failed
> --2021-02-05 18:15:16--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496/server-linux-x64/stable
> Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com
> (update.code.visualstudio.com)... 51.144.164.215 Connecting to
> update.code.visualstudio.com
> (update.code.visualstudio.com)|51.144.164.215|:443... connected.
> ERROR: cannot verify update.code.visualstudio.com's certificate,
> issued by ‘CN=Kaspersky Anti-Virus Personal Root Certificate,O=AO
> Kaspersky Lab’:   Self-signed certificate encountered. To connect to
> update.code.visualstudio.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
> ERROR: Failed to download
> https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496/server-linux-x64/stable
> to
> /home/micha/.vscode-server/bin/8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496-1612545315.tar.gz Please install missing certificates. Debian/Ubuntu:  sudo apt-get
> install ca-certificates

I have already installed ca-certificates without any Problem.

Comment: Just add exception in Kaspersky or copy to /use/local/share/ca-certificates Kaspersky CA certificate and do update-ca-certificates commands.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this error:

1. (Add Last Line to  /etc/wgetrc) - `check_certificate = off`

Results:

> everton@LPEw:/$ code
> Updating VS Code Server to version 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
> Removing previous installation...
> Installing VS Code Server for x64 (3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d)
> Downloading: 100%
> Unpacking: 100%
> Unpacked 1719 files and folders to /home/everton/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d.
> everton@LPEw:/$

Comment: Thanks @BrianTompsett

Comment: From [Wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options): "*Only use this option if you are otherwise convinced of the site’s authenticity, or if you really don’t care about the validity of its certificate.* It is almost always a bad idea not to check the certificates when transmitting confidential or important data."

Answer (score 2):

```
1. go to WSL
then type:
sudo vi /etc/wgetrc
uncomment this line 
#https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
type:
https_proxy = https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496/server-linux-x64/stable:443/
uncomment 
use_proxy = on
type:
check-certificate=off
```

Answer (score 1):

solved this by adding the *update.code.visualstudio.com* domain to the trusted list in kaspersky:

1. open kaspersky
2. click on the setting button (the gear at the bottom left)
3. go to the network setting menu item
4. add the domain to the trusted adresses

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I had to install the Kaspersky certificate as I told in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286450/7724384).

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research I came with a more secure and efficient solution:

1. Open Control Panel, then Internet Options, go to the Content tab and click Certificates.
2. Go to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities tab, select the Kaspersky root certificate and click Export.
3. Follow the instructions. Use the default settings during the certificate export. Enter the name kaspersky.cer for the file.
4. Move the exported .cer file to a Linux folder, open the folder and run this command:

   `openssl x509 -inform DER -in kaspersky.cer -out kaspersky.crt`
5. Copy the created .crt file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`
6. Run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

---

**Sources**: this solution is a devolopment from [Labradorcode's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067901/update-vs-code-and-kaspersky-certificate#comment116813137_66067901) and was based on [a Kaspersky tutorial](https://support.kaspersky.com/14620#block2) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37252887).

Comment: This seems to be the right way. WSL is not trusting the Kaspersky CA. So, we added it to the trusted CAs (that's what I understood). Shouldn't this be handled by Windows itself?