# APACHE 2 WAMP Server not recognizing SSL certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wamp

I created a certificate using OpenSSL. After getting the certificate signed I received a '.CER' file. I followed the instructions from a tutorial ("https://infyom.com/blog/how-to-enable-localhost-https-ssl-on-wamp-server") however I received the following error after running the "httpd - t" command in the command prompt:

AH00526: Syntax error on line 290 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extr
a/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLCACertificateFile: file 'C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/key/[name-of-cert].crt' does not exist or is empty".

I also noted that the certificate extension used in many of these tutorials are ".CRT". I found a question previoulsy asked and one of the answers said that it shouldn't matter but I'm still not sure: [Do I need to convert .CER to .CRT for Apache SSL certificates? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642284/do-i-need-to-convert-cer-to-crt-for-apache-ssl-certificates-if-so-how).

Troubleshooting done so far:

- Changed the directions of the slashes.
- Copied the path from the folder location and pasted it in the configuration
- The configuration files also uses a variable that stores the server
  root and I have tried the path both with and without that server root
  variable.
- When I comment out the line that throws the error the private key that is stored in the same folder is read and the "httpd- t" command outputs "Syntax Ok".

Comment: Did you think of trying the [WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I added the extension while renaming the file so it was stored as "filename.cer.cer". I ran the "httpd- t" command again and it outputted "Syntax Ok".

Hope this helps someone else as well.