# How do I install a certificate in the trusted certificates keystore within WebSphere?

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Our network guy provided us a .cer file in order to install on our laptop running Windows XP with Eclipse and WebSphere. I have seen the following posts:

[using spring-ldap with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431383/using-spring-ldap-with-ssl)

However I am unsure as to where/how to install the .cer file.

I have also seen the following post:

[Digital Certificate: How to import .cer file in to .truststore file using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using)

Again I just don't know what the keystore is. Is it cacerts?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is cacerts. You need to use keytool import command. Keystore option should have path to your cacert location. Here is example on keytool command http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html

Cacerts will be under java_home-jre-lib-security folder.