# ssl certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, wget

This website, https://dcs1.noaa.gov, recently updated their SSL certification.  Since that change I cannot grab a file from there that I need.  I get the following error:

```
--08:37:12--  https://dcs1.noaa.gov/pdts_compressed.txt
           => `pdts_compressed.txt'
Resolving dcs1.noaa.gov... 205.156.2.181
Connecting to dcs1.noaa.gov|205.156.2.181|:443... connected.
ERROR: Certificate verification error for dcs1.noaa.gov: unable to get local issuer certificate
To connect to dcs1.noaa.gov insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I am running Red Hat Linux 4.x and updated all the openssl packages.  The usual process I use to access this file is running in Java and uses URL.openStream() to read the file.  The command wget also does not work so I am assuming that it is an SSL problem and not a java problem.

Comment: I used the help at this link to get java working with the new cert.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the new server certificate is issued by an issuing authority that is not trusted by you. You need to import the issuing authority's certificate in your truststore.

Answer (score 0):

the cert is issued by Verisign, probably their root cert is in your servers root cert store. Open the webpage from your machine from a browser and you will see the cert is valid. You can also try to wget from another machine and it will work too.

Comment: Where is my server root store located?  I have asked Red Hat and the have not answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing the SSL connection with openssl's s_client. I recently had a similar problem and had it resolved. Here's a link to that solution. It also includes information on how to use the s_client to test an SSL connection.

[SSL Error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/24454893#24454893)