# SSL Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: security, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble configuring SSL on a Debian 6.0 32bit server. I'm relatively new with SSL so please bear with me. I'm including as much information as I can.
*Note: The true domain name has been changed to protect the identity and integrity of the server.*

#### Configuration

The server is running using nginx. It is configured as follows:

```
ssl_certificate           /usr/local/nginx/priv/mysite.ca.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /usr/local/nginx/priv/mysite.ca.key;
ssl_protocols             SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_verify_depth          2;
```

I chained my certificate using the method described [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

```
cat mysite.ca.crt bundle.crt > mysite.ca.chained.crt
```

where `mysite.ca.crt` is the certificate given to me by the signing authority, and the `bundle.crt` is the CA certificate also sent to me by my signing authority. The problem is that I did not purchase the SSL certificate directly from GlobalSign, but instead through my hosting provider, Singlehop.

#### Testing

The certificate validates properly on Safari and Chrome, but not on Firefox. Initial searching revealed that it may be a problem with the CA.

I explored the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url), but was unable to find a solution, as I don't really understand what purpose each certificate serves.

I used openssl's s_client to test the connection, and received output which seems to indicate the same problem as [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url). The error is as follows:

```
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.mysite.ca
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.mysite.ca
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
```

A full detail of openssl's response (with certificates and unnecessary information truncated) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jamiecounsell/a3988d56965d81d1a4b0).

I also see the warning:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
```

Is it possible that this is the problem? How can I ensure that nginx sends these CA names?

#### Attempts to Solve the Problem

I attempted to solve the problem by downloading the root CA directly from GlobalSign, but received the same error. I updated the root CA's on my Debian server using the `update-ca-certificates` command, but nothing changed. This is likely because the CA sent from my provider was correct, so it led to the certificate being chained twice, which doesn't help.

```
0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.mysite.ca
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
1 s:/O=AlphaSSL/CN=AlphaSSL CA - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
2 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
```

#### Next Steps

Please let me know if there is anything I can try, or if I just have the whole thing configured incorrectly.

Comment: Your domain cert is signed by issuer `AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2`. However, your chain supplies intermediate `AlphaSSL CA - G2`. I believe you need to delete the current intermediate certificate (`AlphaSSL CA - G2`), and replace it with the one with fingerprint `ae:bf:32:c3:c8:32:c7:d7...` (`AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2`). Also, you *do not* need to send `GlobalSign Root CA`. The client must root its trust their (or on the intermediate).

Comment: You will be able to test this locally with OpenSSL. Try `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -CAfile <GlobalSign Root CA.pem>`. The command should complete with a `Verify OK (0)` or similar. When you get the `Verify OK (0)`, the server is configured properly (for this issue).

Comment: When you download that new intermediate, you will need to convert it to PEM with `openssl x509 -in gsalphasha2g2.crt -inform DER -out Alpha-SHA256-G2.pem -outform PEM`.

Comment: Beautiful. I believe it's working now. For some reason I thought I tried to get the SHA 256 one, but I must have failed to convert it properly. Thank you, sincerely.

Comment: yeah, the thing to look for are the Subject-Issuer pairs walking back to a root or CA. OpenSSL displays them as `i:` and `s:` under `s_client`. Once you have the certs you need, concat all of them *except* the root. Because they are concat'd, they need to be in PEM format. The URL was helpful. Its getting old trying to help folks who won't provide information so we can look at it locally with `s_client`. (If you did not provide the URL, I would have voted to close).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind (posting URL). Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

jww is right — you're referencing the wrong intermediate certificate.

As you have been issued with a SHA256 certificate, you will need the SHA256 intermediate. You can grab it from here: http://secure2.alphassl.com/cacert/gsalphasha2g2r1.crt