# PHP Laravel web scrape get_meta_tags

Tags: php, ssl, curl, web-scraping

Im using Laravel 5.2 for web scraping meta tags but I am having issues with the `get_meta_tags()`.

It seems that there are timeout and/or cURL issues with looped `get_meta_tags()`.

Take this as an example.

```
$urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', ...];
foreach ($urls as $value) {
    $meta = get_meta_tags($value);
}
```

Let's say I have 10 values under the `$urls` array then do a loop for `get_meta_tags()`. Would it have any issues with regards to performance? This is because I am getting intermittent errors at random URLs which displays:

> get_meta_tags(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is
>   usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that
>   the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative
>   server.

or sometimes

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

But when I get the meta tags one-by-one: `get_meta_tags('http://google.com')` instead inside the loop, I am able to retrieve successfully.

And since I am doing a batch web scraping, I have to do a loop which is batched by 10s.

I even set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
```

I am also using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) for web scraping DOM (links, title, h1). And since I can't get meta tags using Goutte, I use `get_meta_tags()` instead. But if Goutte has the ability to get meta tags without any issue on it inside a loop, then that would be great.

Comment: Why exactly can't Goutte get meta tags, as you are stating?

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are not your code's fault :P

This code works:

```
<?php
    $urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
    foreach ($urls as $value) {
        $meta = get_meta_tags($value);
        print_r($meta);
    }    
?>
```

Your errors:

1. First Error : `get_meta_tags(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.`

This usually happens when you are unable to connect to your DNS(i.e. not able to resolve a website's name). This issue is typically caused by the Apache/PHP host unable to contact the DNS server. This could happen for various other reasons like ISP issues, config issues, etc (some of them being temporary issues as said in the error itself).

Fix to this : [Fix: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/)

2. Second Error : `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Fix for this error : [SSL Error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Read:

- [How to fix PHP CURL Error 60 SSL](http://flwebsites.biz/posts/how-fix-curl-error-60-ssl-issue)
- [Fix certificate issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/37017)