# How to use coinbase API for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

Is there anyone experience with using coinbase API for node.js

I am following the [npm coinbase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase) documentation but It is not working. I am simply trying to get the price of the bitcoin. I did first installed coinbase between, so that is not the problem.

```
const config = require('../configuration')
const coinbase = require('coinbase')

const apiKey = config.get('COINBASE_API_KEY')
const apiSecret = config.get('COINBASE_API_SECRET')

const client = new coinbase.Client({apiKey, apiSecret})

module.exports = {
  start: async () => {
    client.getBuyPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, obj) {
      console.log('total amount: ' + obj.data.amount);
    });
  }
}
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error:

> > C:\Users\msaad\VisualStudioProjects\CryptoTrader-master\session-1>node index.js
> >     C:\Users\msaad\VisualStudioProjects\CryptoTrader-master\session-1\src\app\index.js:12
> >           console.log('total amount: ' + obj.data.amount);
> >
> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

It always returns NULL when I run it.

Comment: Can you console log obj?

Comment: when I try to log just the obj, it runs but it also returns: total amount: null

Comment: That's why `obj.data.amount` is giving you an error. Are you sure the parameters you're passing in to the `getBuyPrice` function is correct?

Comment: Try run the getBuyPrice function without exporting and wrapping it into an async and see what it does.

Comment: It still returns null. Could it be because my API key is still disabled? It said on my coin base account that the API key enables after 48 hours when created.

Comment: That could be the case. But usually that will give you a 401 unauthorized. Maybe check back 48hrs later to see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable SSL for your client.

```
const { apiKey, apiSecret } = require('./config.js');
const Client = require('coinbase').Client;

const myClient = new Client({ 'apiKey':apiKey, 'apiSecret':apiSecret, 
strictSSL:false });

myClient.getBuyPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, obj){
    if(err) console.log("Error: ", err);
    console.log("Total Amount: ", obj.data.amount);
});
```

Alternatively you can get and use SSL certificates as explained in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961069/coinbase-api-client-getaccount-started-returning-error-unable-to-get-loc) question.

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one getting a bunch of warnings about severe vulnerabilities after installing the 'coinbase' npm package and running `npm audit`?  I can't find anything about it when Googling, and all guides on fetching data from Coinbase with node.js seems to focus on using that package...

Comment: The Coinbase-Node project [is deprecated](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node).