# Is it possible to open self-signed java applet with java version 7 update 51 without decreasing security level

Tags: java, security, applet, self-signed

An application run as java applet suddenly stopps working with default java security settings.

The reason is that this applet uses a self-signed certificate.

Is it possible to get it starting again without lowering the security level configured within the Java control panel? Is there any workaround?

Comment: You might also consider packaging your application up using something like Launch4j, JarSplice, or JWrapper.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suggest using a certificate signed by a good Certificate Authority (CA). If you can modify the client machine, it is possible to add your own CA, but the practice is frowned upon for being somewhat dodgy.

Comment: Java uses its own list of CAs also. [How to import .cer file in to .truststore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using). Search for "code-signing certificate".

Answer (score 1):

You may try the exception list feature as descibed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/exception_site_list.html) or [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in).