# Ignore/Turn off verification of the certificate in Jmeter/Java

Tags: java, jmeter, ssl-certificate, keystore, ca

I am testing HTTPS Requests to a custom server using JMeter, but the certificate that the custom server returns in untrusted (as this is a development server). Because of this, the requests fail as it needs a signed/verified CA Certificate.

Is there a way to turn off Jmeter's certificate verification similar to curl (-k option) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the certificate from the development server in Jmeter jvm.

1. Download the certificate using any of the browsers. Here is a [link](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file) on how to do this.
2. Identify the jvm that Jmeter uses. This is generally your JAVA_HOME environment varaible.
3. Add the certificate to the jvm truststore. Here are the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using).

That should fix it.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? You didn't even answer his question. He asked how to turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

JMeter does not validate certificates by default, it ignores all certificate errors such as expiry and incorrect hostname. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterAndHTTPS

If you are still facing this issue, then you can explicitly mention the properties to ignore ssl certificate check. It can be done in two ways,

1. Add a JMeter start-up configuration. You just have to look for the jmeter.properties file and add the code line ‘server.rmi.ssl.disable=true’
2. Executing Jmeter through command line by passing parameter to rewrite properties of the configuration files at start-up,

   jmeter -s -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true

Also check if correct headers are passed,

```
Accept-Enconding= application/json
Content-Type= application/json
```