# RestTemplate with pem certificate

Tags: java, spring, authentication, resttemplate, pem

I have pem certificate with private key and server certificate.
I can execute it using curl and all works ok.

```
curl -O -k --cert-type pem --cert mypem.pem url
```

But I want to use it with java, most preferably will be RestTemplate from spring.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So knowledge about using pem certificate with RestTemplate is distracted.

Steps which must be done:

1. Add server certificate to trustStore, using keytool or portecle. When you want to use custom trusttore use this [script](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java)
2. Next configure ssl to RestTemplate. It may be done like below:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class SSLConfiguration {

   @Value("${certificate.name}")
   private String name;

   @Bean(name = "sslContext")
   public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {
     Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
     return SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).useTLS().build();
   }

   @Bean(name = "sslSocketFactory")
   public SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory() throws Exception {

     return new ConnectionFactoryCreator(name, sslContext()).getSocketFactory();

   }

   @Bean(name = "httpClient")
   public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
     return HttpClientBuilder.create().setSslcontext(sslContext())
           .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory(), new AllowAllHostnameVerifier()))
           .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpClientRequestFactory() throws Exception {
     return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
   }

   @Bean
   public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
     return new RestTemplate(httpClientRequestFactory());
    }

   }
   ```

and

```
public class ConnectionFactoryCreator {

   private final String pemName;

   private final SSLContext context;

   public ConnectionFactoryCreator(String pemName, SSLContext context) {
      this.pemName = pemName;
      this.context = context;
   }

   public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() throws Exception {

      InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(pemName);
  byte[] certAndKey = ByteStreams.toByteArray(resourceAsStream);

  byte[] certBytes = parseDERFromPEM(certAndKey, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
  byte[] keyBytes = parseDERFromPEM(certAndKey, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

  X509Certificate cert = generateCertificateFromDER(certBytes);

  PrivateKey key = generatePrivateKeyFromDER(keyBytes);

  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
  keystore.load(null);
  keystore.setCertificateEntry("cert-alias", cert);
  keystore.setKeyEntry("key-alias", key, "changeit".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] { cert });

  KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
  kmf.init(keystore, "changeit".toCharArray());

  KeyManager[] km = kmf.getKeyManagers();

  context.init(km, null, null);

  return context.getSocketFactory();
   }

   private byte[] parseDERFromPEM(byte[] pem, String beginDelimiter, String endDelimiter) {
  String data = new String(pem);
  String[] tokens = data.split(beginDelimiter);
  tokens = tokens[1].split(endDelimiter);
  return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(tokens[0]);
   }

   private PrivateKey generatePrivateKeyFromDER(byte[] keyBytes)
     throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

  KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

  return factory.generatePrivate(spec);
   }

   private X509Certificate generateCertificateFromDER(byte[] certBytes) throws CertificateException {
  CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

  return (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes));
 }
```

Finally you can use inject restTemplate to connect to url.

Comment: It looks like useful, but could you show how to use your code with `RestTemplate`? Thanks

Comment: @BSeitkazin, use it as normal

```@Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate; 
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the certificate in the java trust store.

*BTW pem and cer(t) files are the same, just a different name for the extension*

Additional links

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html
- [Digital Certificate: How to import .cer file in to .truststore file using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using)

Comment: During import I have: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate