# How to obtain public key from an SSL connection

Tags: java, ssl, resttemplate, public-key

I have a REST service that I access via https. The parameters to the service include clear-text passwords which, at TRACE level logging appear in log files. To avoid inadvertent logging of these details I want to encrypt the passwords before sending, the obvious way (to me, at least) to do this being to use the public key of the https connection.

I don't want to disable the logging because the detail is sometimes useful and it would be very simple to inadvertently re-enable it.

I'm using Spring RestTemplate.

How do I get hold of the public key?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497874/resttemplate-with-pem-certificate

Comment: @VaibhavSharma - I may be missing something but that looks like it's getting the private key from a file-based certificate.

Comment: Passwords should be sent via POST.

Comment: They **are** being sent by POST...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have solved this is by making a HttpsURLConnection connection to the server.

```
KeyStore keyStore = loadKeystore(keystoreFilename, keystorePassword);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

KeyStore trustStore = loadKeystore(truststoreFilename, truststorePassword);
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new java.security.SecureRandom());

URL destinationURL = new URL(origin);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
conn.connect();

return conn.getServerCertificates();

private KeyStore loadKeystore(String keyStoreFilename, String keyStorePassword) {
    try {
        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFilename);
        trustStore.load(is, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        return trustStore;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new MyException(ex);
    }
}
```

This returns an array of certificates, the first element being the peer's certificate from which the public key can be obtained.