# Failed to execute goal on project in Maven

Tags: maven, confluence

when i trying to build the maven project its giving me below error

error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project unstoppable-confluence: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.addteq.confluence.plugin.unstoppable:unstoppable-confluence:atlassian-plugin:1.3: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.confluence:confluence:jar:6.0.2 -> com.atlassian.security:atlassian-secure-xml:jar:3.2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.security:atlassian-secure-xml:jar:3.2.4: Could not transfer artifact com.atlassian.pom:closedsource-pom:pom:3.0.2 from/to atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

---

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.addteq.confluence.plugin.unstoppable</groupId>
<artifactId>unstoppable-confluence</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>

<organization>
    <name>Addteq</name>
    <url>https://www.addteq.com</url>
</organization>

<name>Unstoppable-Confluence</name>
<description>This is Addteq's Unstoppable plugin for Atlassian Confluence.</description>
<packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:svn:https://svn2.worldnet.ml.com/svnrepos/gmrt_architecture_repo/code-confluence-accessibility/trunk
    </developerConnection>
    <connection>
        scm:svn:https://svn2.worldnet.ml.com/svnrepos/gmrt_architecture_repo/code-confluence-accessibility/trunk
    </connection>
    <url>
        scm:svn:https://svn2.worldnet.ml.com/svnrepos/gmrt_architecture_repo/code-confluence-accessibility/trunk
    </url>
</scm>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
        <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
        <version>${confluence.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.upm</groupId>
        <artifactId>licensing-api</artifactId>
        <version>${upm.license.compatibility.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.upm</groupId>
        <artifactId>upm-api</artifactId>
        <version>${upm.license.compatibility.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
        <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>confluence-rest-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                <!--<productDataPath>${basedir}/src/test/resources/generated-test-resources.zip</productDataPath>-->
                <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                <instructions>                        
                    <DynamicImport-Package>com.atlassian.upm.api.license.entity;version="2.0.1", com.atlassian.upm.api.license;version="2.0.1", com.atlassian.upm.api.util;version="2.0.1", com.atlassian.upm.license.storage.plugin;version="${upm.license.compatibility.version}"</DynamicImport-Package>
                </instructions>          
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <confluence.version>6.0.2</confluence.version>
    <confluence.data.version>6.0.2</confluence.data.version>
    <amps.version>6.2.6</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.0</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <upm.license.compatibility.version>2.20.4</upm.license.compatibility.version>
    <upm.license.storage.compatibility.version>2.15.3</upm.license.storage.compatibility.version>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian</id>
        <name>Atlassian Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

can someone suggest me how to get rid of this error.

and also i have external jars that I directly  added from build path> configure build path>

addteq-jira-unstoppable-1.2.jar & 
unstoppable-confluence-1.3.2.jar

Comment: Your problem is this: ` sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As khmarbaise mentioned, the error you are getting is: *sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

Your local keystore (truststore) does not contain the required certificates. Once you add the required certs it will start working. You can do that by following these steps:

- Copy the URL into the browser and download the certs

  - http://www.wikihow.com/Export-Certificate-Public-Key-from-Chrome
  - http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website
- Import cert into keystore

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java-add-certificate-ca-store
  - [Digital Certificate: How to import .cer file in to .truststore file using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using)
- You may also have to restart your JVM / IDE if running maven from within IDE

The article below from Atlassian describes a similar issue and provides a solution to the problem: https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

To add JAR's directly the correct steps can be found at:

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html