# how to add certificate to Java trust store if keytool is not provided

Tags: java, truststore, sonarscanner

There's a tool [sonar-scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/) written in Java. It has a JRE shipped with it. Currently I met an issue when using this tool, the solution leads to: I need to add certificate to Java trust store with `keytool`. But there's no `keytool` in the shipped JRE.

I'm new to Java. Is there any suggestions of how to add the certificate in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: The keytool is part of the JDK you can install one and use the keytool of it

Comment: The `keytool` is part of JRE 1.8 and all other JREs I have ever used back to the old security tool whatever it was called in 1.1. Use that.

Comment: find at path {jre}\bin\keytool. path to jre by default you can find run "java -verbose -version"

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Later I found out I can use `keytool` to create the trust store e.g. in my macbook, and use that to replace the one shipped with sonar-scanner in `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373307/1476512)