# Maven build fails due to Certificate for <packages.atlassian.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app: Could not resolve dependencies for project app:war:RELEASE: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.0.M1, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.0.M1, javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec:jar:1.1.3, javax.media.jai:com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core:jar:1.1.3: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.M1 from/to atlassian-public (https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public): Transfer failed for https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.M1/spring-core-5.2.0.M1.jar: Certificate for <packages.atlassian.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.services.atlassian.com, services.atlassian.com] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Provide the specific source code (or isolated sample) for more details, as well as the result you are getting and the expected result. This will help to get more response from the community.

Comment: Looks like you're using a custom repo as opposed to maven central?

Comment: Add the certificate of that repository to your trusted ones, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using) to know how to do it